# Pass array as selected to select2 field on form view in rails aplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

In my ruby on rails application i have a class called @card, that have few fields of tags that are select2, for example:

```
<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true} %>
```

The value of `@card.tag_location` can be for example: `["", "Asa Norte", "Asa Sul"]` or `["", "Lago Norte", "Asa Sul"]`

I am trying to have this field marked as selected with the values of the array on the UPDATE view:

I tried:

1) `<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location, :selected => params[:tag_location]), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true} %>`

2) `<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location, params[:tag_location]), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true} %>`

3) `<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true, data: {selected: @card.tag_location}} %>`

3) `<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true, data: {selected: @card.tag_location.drop(1)}} %>`

And i could not find a way to have the selected value working, could some one help ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, don't understand why, but it worked

```
<%= f.select :tag_location, options_from_array_for_select(@domain.tag_location, @card.tag_location), {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) instead of `options_from_array_for_select` which would create a set of `<option></option>` tag for you from the passed collection.

You can have a dropdown like this:

```
<%= f.select :tag_location, @domain.tag_location, {:include_blank => "Escolha uma opção"} , {class: 'form-control', multiple: true} %>
```